# Python Linkledlist addNode() not correct

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes

I'm writing a simple linked list implementation and am struggling to understand why my code doesn't work. I have a ListNode class and a LinkedList node which contains the `head` and `tail` nodes of the list. The `addNode()` function simply creates a new `ListNode`, change the `self.tail.next = newNode`, then set the tail to be the `newNode`.

When I try to run the following code, I would get the error "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'".

```
l1 = LinkedList(1)
l1.addNode(2)
l1.addNode(4)
```

Thank you for the help!

Here is my code

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
    
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head=ListNode()):
        self.head = head
        self.tail = head
    
    def addNode(self, val=0):
        newNode = ListNode(val)
        self.tail.next = newNode
        self.tail = newNode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first line of your code, you're passing the value `1` to `LinkedList`, which is an integer, not an instance of `ListNode`.

So, you should write `l1 = LinkedList(ListNode(1))`.

Comment: You're right. Thank you for helping. I was going crazy from not understanding what went wrong.